# Change Pagination with out refresh que Select

Tags: pagination, oracle-apex, refresh, oracle-apex-5.1

I have a problem, I need to use the pagination in a Classic Report but it can't make a new select on database, it must do just once to take the data, after that I need to use the pagination with out refresh the data. I've tried to disable the Partial Page Refresh, but if I do it. It doesn't work anymore. I tried to create a button to refresh the report when I click it but it also doesn't work [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xp4La.png)

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking for here. There must be a refresh/query between the browser and the database - the browser can't store the entire result set to facilitate pagination.

Answer (score 1):

You only described the problem, not the entire scenario, so what I'm describing below might not be optimal.
If you only want to run the select statement once then you could store the results of your query in a collection ([apex_collection API](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_collection.htm#AEAPI651)) and then create the classic report on the collection.

This way the results of the initial query are stored in session state and can be accessed by selecting from `APEX_COLLECTIONS`. You can paginate through the resultset without re-executing the query.

Example against EMP table:

1. Create a pre-rendering page process to populate the collection with source:

```
DECLARE
  l_query VARCHAR2(4000);
Begin
  IF APEX_COLLECTION.COLLECTION_EXISTS (p_collection_name => 'EMP') THEN
    APEX_COLLECTION.DELETE_COLLECTION (p_collection_name => 'EMP');
  END IF;
    l_query := q'!
select EMPNO,
       ENAME,
       JOB,
       MGR,
       HIREDATE,
       SAL,
       COMM,
       DEPTNO
  from EMP!';
    APEX_COLLECTION.CREATE_COLLECTION_FROM_QUERY (
        p_collection_name => 'EMP', 
        p_query => l_query);
END;
```

2. Create a classic report agains APEX_COLLECTIONS

```
SELECT C001 AS EMPNO,
       C002 AS ENAME,
       C003 AS JOB,
       C004 AS MGR,
       C005 AS HIREDATE,
       C006 AS SAL,
       C007 AS COMM,
       C008 AS DEPTNO
  FROM apex_collections 
 WHERE collection_name = 'EMP';
```